# Is it possible to use a c# dll in Qt?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, dll, sdk

I am writing a program that utilises a c# sdk. The functionality of this program will be used in a larger program written in c++ using QtCreator. I would like to create a c# dll to interact with the sdk and then consume this in the c++ program. Has anyone done this before and can point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, I do this regularly at work. You can consume C# from C++ using COM and Interop. Worth noting now that this is all windows only.

If you've not used COM from C++ before you are in for a nasty surprise. It's fairly unpleasant.

This is a very big topic, so I can't really cover it in a post, but if you want to learn more, I'd look here for starting on the C++ side:

[COM(C++) programming tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938435/comc-programming-tutorials)

I'd recommend using ATL to make your COM life a lot easier.

EDIT: Actually I didn't know this, but Qt has COM support, so you'd be much better off using that - Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/activeqt-index.html

Google around for the C# side, but it's mostly about using the ComVisible and Guid attributes on your classes to make them COM ready and then registering them using regasm.exe (Part of the .NET Framework).

Comment: nice to add to your answer the qt side of the task

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise Qt had ActiveX/COM support so added a link to the Qt docs.

Comment: That is the most help in one place i've been able to find anywhere. Thanks very much.